# How to channel the flow of data between modules in a reactive R Shiny App?

Tags: r, shiny, module

I'm trying to understand how to direct the flow of data between modules in a Shiny App. I would  like data to flow from Base App to Module 1 for processing, then the processed data from Module 2 goes back to Base App which is then sent back out to Module 2 for additional processing; and the results of both Module 1 and Module 2 are shown to the user via the Shiny UI.

The reason I would like Module 1 data to go back to the Base App before being sent back out to Module 2 is that Module 1 and Module 2 will eventually have some back and forth, where the data flow goes both ways. In the simple example below the data flow is only one way. Maybe the data doesn't need to go back to the Base App before being sent on to Module 2, I need more experienced guidance.

Anyhow, the code at the bottom sort of gets me there. As illustrated below, I would like to change the code so the results are output as shown below. This will help me see the data flow in the code. Any recommendation for how to do this? I'm also open to any suggestion for simplification: maybe the Module 1 data can be sent directly to Module 2 without having to go back to the server section of the Base App? (Keeping in mind that Module 1 and Module 2 will eventually have a two-way flow of data).

When running the code below, Module 1 multiplies the base data table by the slider input value; Module 2 adds 10 to the products of Module 1.

[image]

Code is saved in 3 separate R files:

**BASE APP**

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

source("C:/Users/.../Flow_module1_Aug07_2023.R")

ui <- fluidPage(
  mainPanel(
    h5(strong("Base table:")),
    DTOutput("table"),
    h5(strong("Module 1 multiplies slider input by values in above table:")),
    sliderInput("svc", '', min = 0, max = 10, value = 1),
    allocTbl_ui("tblModule"),
    h5(strong("Module 2 then adds 10 to those Module 1 products:"))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  df <- data.frame(A = 1:3, B = 4:6, C = 7:9)
  output$table <- renderDT({datatable(df)})
  
  # store returned value from first module
  upd_dat <- allocTbl_server(
    "tblModule",
    df = reactive(df),
    svc = reactive(input$svc),
    upd_dat_2 = upd_dat_2
    )
  
  # send this returned value to second module
  upd_dat_2 <- mod_2_server('mod2', upd_dat)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**MODULE 1: multiplies original DF by slider input value**

```
source("C:/Users/.../Flow_module2_Aug07_2023.R")

allocTbl_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  DTOutput(ns("tbl"))
}

allocTbl_server <- function(id, df, svc, upd_dat_2) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    
    new_dat <- reactive({
      df() * as.numeric(svc())
    })
    
    output$tbl <- renderDT({
      upd_dat_2_clean <- upd_dat_2()
      colnames(upd_dat_2_clean) <- 
        paste0(colnames(upd_dat_2_clean), "_10")
      table_data <- cbind(new_dat(), upd_dat_2_clean)
      datatable(table_data)
    })
    return(new_dat)
  })
}
```

**MODULE 2: adds 10 to df**

```
mod_2_server <- function(id, upd_dat2){
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session){
    upd_dat_2 <- reactive({
      upd_dat2() + 10
    })
    return(upd_dat_2)
  })
}
```

**Posting a simpler code example and diagram of reactive data flows based on smartse answer:**

```
library(shiny)

mod1_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  list(textOutput(ns("result1")))
}

mod1_server <- function(id, common) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    result1 <- reactive({common$sharedValue + 10})
    output$result1 <- renderText({paste("Mod 1 Result = base + 10:",result1())})
    observe({common$mod1Value <- result1()})
  })
}

mod2_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  list(textOutput(ns("result2")))
}

mod2_server <- function(id, common) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    result2 <- reactive({common$mod1Value * 2})
    output$result2 <- renderText({
      paste("Mod 2 Result = Mod 1 Result * 2:", result2())
      })
  })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  mainPanel(
    h5(strong("Base value:")),
    sliderInput("svc", "", min = 0, max = 10, value = 0),
    mod1_ui("mod1"),
    mod2_ui("mod2")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  common <- reactiveValues(
    sharedValue = 0,
    mod1Value = 0
    )
  observeEvent(input$svc, {common$sharedValue <- input$svc})
  mod1_server("mod1", common)
  mod2_server("mod2", common)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Illustration of above code data flows:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do the plotting from a UI part of `mod_2`. Notice how you can reuse the UI part from the first module:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

allocTbl_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  DTOutput(ns("tbl"))
}

allocTbl_server <- function(id, df, svc, upd_dat_2) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    
    new_dat <- reactive({
      df() * as.numeric(svc())
    })
    
    output$tbl <- renderDT({
      new_dat()
    })
    return(new_dat)
  })
}

mod_2_server <- function(id, upd_dat2){
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session){
    upd_dat_2 <- reactive({
      upd_dat2() + 10
    })
    
    output$tbl <- renderDT({
      upd_dat_2()
    })
    
    return(upd_dat_2)
  })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  mainPanel(
    h5(strong("Base table:")),
    DTOutput("table"),
    h5(strong("Module 1 multiplies slider input by values in above table:")),
    sliderInput("svc", '', min = 0, max = 10, value = 1),
    allocTbl_ui("tblModule"),
    h5(strong("Module 2 then adds 10 to those Module 1 products:")),
    allocTbl_ui("mod2")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  df <- data.frame(A = 1:3, B = 4:6, C = 7:9)
  output$table <- renderDT({datatable(df)})
  
  # store returned value from first module
  upd_dat <- allocTbl_server(
    "tblModule",
    df = reactive(df),
    svc = reactive(input$svc),
    upd_dat_2 = upd_dat_2
  )
  
  # send this returned value to second module
  upd_dat_2 <- mod_2_server('mod2', upd_dat)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

If you use one module only for calculation and don't necessarily need a UI for it, you could use a function instead of a module. Here is a solution that replaces `mod_2` with a function:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

allocTbl_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  DTOutput(ns("tbl"))
}

allocTbl_server <- function(id, df, svc, upd_dat_2) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    
    new_dat <- reactive({
      df() * as.numeric(svc())
    })
    
    output$tbl <- renderDT({
      new_dat()
    })
    return(new_dat)
  })
}

mod_2_server <- function(id, upd_dat2){
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session){
    upd_dat_2 <- reactive({
      upd_dat2() + 10
    })
    
    output$tbl <- renderDT({
      upd_dat_2()
    })
    
    return(upd_dat_2)
  })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  mainPanel(
    h5(strong("Base table:")),
    DTOutput("table"),
    h5(strong("Module 1 multiplies slider input by values in above table:")),
    sliderInput("svc", '', min = 0, max = 10, value = 1),
    allocTbl_ui("tblModule"),
    h5(strong("Module 2 then adds 10 to those Module 1 products:")),
    allocTbl_ui("mod2")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  df <- data.frame(A = 1:3, B = 4:6, C = 7:9)
  output$table <- renderDT({datatable(df)})
  
  # store returned value from first module
  upd_dat <- allocTbl_server(
    "tblModule",
    df = reactive(df),
    svc = reactive(input$svc),
    upd_dat_2 = upd_dat_2
  )
  
  # send this returned value to second module
  upd_dat_2 <- mod_2_server('mod2', upd_dat)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to use modules, it is probably best to have all of the functionality in modules and only load them in the main app. There are various ways that you can pass your data between them so that they can access all of the data. Let's say you have this in the main app, so that each module is passed `common`:

```
  callModule(mod1_server, "mod1", common)
  callModule(mod2_server, "mod2", common)
```

And then in your modules you have this:

```
mod1_server <- function(input, output, session, common) {}
mod2_server <- function(input, output, session, common) {}
```

`common` can then be various objects:

#### Reactive values

Add `common <- reactiveValues()` to the main app and then assign whatever you like to `common$xyz` inside the modules, which is then accessible inside all of them. I haven't found an explanation of why not to do this, but I have read various things hinting at it being bad practice, but it probably depends on the size and complexity of your app.

#### List

Similar to the above, but `common` is a `list` which contains `reactiveValues()`:

```
my_data <- reactiveValues()
more_data <- reactiveValues()
common <- list(my_data=my_data, 
               more_data=more_data)
```

Then you can either assign to `common$my_data$xyz` etc. or create `my_data <- common$my_data` inside your modules, and then assigning to `my_data$xyz` will also update `common`.

#### R6

I've seen people recommend passing an R6 object between modules like below. One difference compared to the previous methods is you need to define your first layer of objects (i.e. `my_data` below) prior to assigning anything to them whereas this isn't necessary if `common` is `reactiveValues()`, but you can still assign to `common$my_data$xyz` inside your modules. One thing to note with this method, is that you can lose reactivity in which case you need to use `library(gargoyle)` to add it back using `init()`, `trigger()` and `watch()`.

```
common_class <- R6::R6Class(
    classname = "common",
    public = list(
      my_data = NULL)

 common <- common_class$new()
```

Sorry I haven't adapted your code, but it looks like it needs a lot of refactoring to fit these methods of passing data between them. Hopefully this gives you more of an idea about how to approach it though.

Comment: I added to the OP a simpler code example to reflect your recommendation along with a diagram of the data flow between modules.