# Shiny: How to pass an input from one module to another?

Tags: r, shiny

I want to access an input from a submodule, how can I do it?

Below is my demo code, in which I want to print out the `colName` input from inner module in outer module.

```r
library(golem)
library(shiny)

#1. Define the inner module
inner_module_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  fluidPage(
    h1("Inner Module"),
    selectInput(inputId = ns("colName"),
                label = "Select a column name",
                choices = list("A", "B", "C"),
                selected = "A"
                ),
    textOutput(outputId = ns("IOP"))
  )
}

inner_module_server <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    output$IOP <- renderPrint({
      input$colName
    })

})}

#2. Define the outer module
outer_module_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  fluidPage(
    h1("Outer Module"),
    inner_module_ui(ns("inner_module")),
    textOutput(outputId = ns("OOP"))
  )
}

outer_module_server <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    innerModule <- inner_module_server("inner_module")
    output$OOP <- renderPrint({
      input$colName
    })
  })
}

#3. Define the main app
app_server <- function(input, output, session) {
  outer_module_server("outer_module")
}

app_ui <- function() {
  tabPanel("Outer Module", outer_module_ui("outer_module"))
}

#4. Run app
shinyApp(app_ui, app_server)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to update shiny module with reactive dataframe from another module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68584478/how-to-update-shiny-module-with-reactive-dataframe-from-another-module)

Comment: @Limey, I feel like it is a bit different, my inner module is a submodule, which I don't introduce it into the main server.

Comment: The same principles apply.  Try it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that you only want to print the colname in the outer module and not in the inner module you could:

1. let the inner module return a reactive containing the input value
2. access this reactive by assiging it to a variable and use parentheses on it `()`

Code below, my add-ons are marked with `# NEW:`:

```r
library(golem)
library(shiny)

#1. Define the inner module
inner_module_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  fluidPage(
    h1("Inner Module"),
    selectInput(inputId = ns("colName"),
                label = "Select a column name",
                choices = list("A", "B", "C"),
                selected = "A"
    )
  )
}

inner_module_server <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {

    # NEW: just return a reactive containing the col input
    reactive(input$colName)
    
  })}

#2. Define the outer module
outer_module_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  fluidPage(
    h1("Outer Module"),
    inner_module_ui(ns("inner_module")),
    textOutput(outputId = ns("OOP"))
  )
}

outer_module_server <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    innerModule <- inner_module_server("inner_module")
    output$OOP <- renderPrint({
      # NEW: access the content of the reactive with `()`
      innerModule()
    })
  })
}

#3. Define the main app
app_server <- function(input, output, session) {
  outer_module_server("outer_module")
}

app_ui <- function() {
  tabPanel("Outer Module", outer_module_ui("outer_module"))
}

#4. Run app
shinyApp(app_ui, app_server)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your kind help. It works. My real app is more complicated, I want to return different input from a submodule, and use it in other modules.  is there a way to access the inner module input like `innerModule$input$colName` or similar?

Comment: I am sorry to bother you again. I have another question, such returned input is a global variable, which can be accessed by different modules, right? I have already defined few global variables for communications between different modules, it seems now I have to introduce some sort of global variable again in order to access some inputs from submodules. Maybe the use of submodule is not a good idea. what do you think?

Comment: There’s nothing wrong with using a sub module. If any module’s “output” is required by many other modules, consider using `session$userData`.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63183085/can-i-maintain-input-defaults-across-different-instances-of-a-shiny-app-module) or [here](https://shiny.posit.co/r/reference/shiny/1.7.4/session.html).

Comment: See my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/76854827/5599595 which has various options for sharing data between modules. You can't access `innerModule$input$colName` but you can assign it to `<whatever>$innerModule$colName` inside the module and then use it in other modules